# Como relacionar várias tabelas?

Tags: mysql, sql

Abaixo coloquei um exemplo que fiz no excel. Como faz um `select` que troca os valores da tabela `inf_musicas` pelo valor das outras tabelas correspondentes?

OBS: Sei o básico de SQL, sei que usa `inner JOIN` ou também pode ser feito com `exists` e ainda tem um terceiro jeito. O problema é que só sei fazer com duas tabelas e não desse jeito. Alguém pode me mostrar como seria uma query de `SELECT` para fazer o que eu quero?

Obrigado

[image: Tabelas]

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o que você quer é isso:

```
SELECT
    m.id_inf_mus AS id,
    b.nome_banda AS banda,
    g.nome_grava AS gravadora,
    q.quant_cd AS cds
FROM inf_musicas m
INNER JOIN banda b ON m.id_banda = b.id_banda
INNER JOIN gravadora g ON m.id_grava = g.id_grava
INNER JOIN quanti q ON m.id_qnt_cds = q.id_qnt_cds
```

Answer (score 1):

O procedimento é o mesmo que com duas tabelas, só acrescentar uma junção para as demais tabelas:

```
SELECT 
  X.ID_INF_MUS, 
  A.NOME_BANDA, 
  B.NOME_GRAVA, 
  C.QUANT_CD 
FROM INF_MUSICAS X
INNER JOIN BANDA A ON X.ID_BANDA = A.ID_BANDA
INNER JOIN GRAVADORA B ON X.ID_GRAVA = B.ID_GRAVA
INNER JOIN QUANTI C ON X.ID_QNT_CDS = C.ID_QNT_CDS
```

Veja em funcionamento no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12ca3/3).