# como faço inner join com essas tabelas?

Tags: mysql, sql

Como seria a query SELECT em Mysql da tabela Inf_musicas?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que você quer retornar?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como relacionar varias tabelas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/276544/como-relacionar-varias-tabelas)

Comment: sim! quero um select

Comment: Você poderia explicar melhor o que você quer? [Nessa sua outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276544/132) você explicou um pouco melhor ao dizer que queria trocar os valores das chaves estrangeiras de `inf_musicas` pelos valores das demais tabelas. É isso que você quer fazer aqui? Se sim, qual é a dificuldade específica que não é elucidada na sua outra questão? Se não, então o que é que você precisa?

Answer (score 2):

Supondo que sejam essas as tabela:

**Tabela de Integrantes**

```
CREATE TABLE Integrantes(
   ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   Nome NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
);
```

**Tabela de Bandas**

```
CREATE TABLE Bandas(
   ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   Banda NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   IntegranteID INT NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT FK_IntegrantesDaBanda
   FOREIGN KEY (IntegranteID)
   REFERENCES Integrantes.ID
);
```

**Tabela de Gravadoras**

```
CREATE TABLE Gravadoras(
   ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   Gravadora NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
);
```

**Tabela de Músicas**

```
CREATE TABLE Musicas(
   ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   Musica NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   BandaID INT NOT NULL,
   GravadoraID INT NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT FK_MusicaDaBanda
   FOREIGN KEY (BandaID)
   REFERENCES Bandas.ID,

  CONSTRAINT FK_MusicaDaGravadora
   FOREIGN KEY (GravadoraID)
   REFERENCES Gravadoras.ID
);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT M.Musica, B.Banda, G.Gravadora FROM Musicas AS M
INNER JOIN Bandas AS B ON M.BandaID = B.ID
INNER JOIN Gravadoras AS G ON M.GravadoraID = G.ID
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: mais como faço a associação com integrantes?  e eu estou capiando e colando esta dando erro!

Comment: Existe uma foreign key em banda que associa os integrantes a banda... Copiar e colar nao vai ajudar, voce usou dados diferentes na sua criação. Do que vc precisa?